# Django to_field not working

Tags: django

I have two tables `RoomPriceDetails` and `HotelDetails`. `RoomPriceDetails` has a foreign key which I want to point to the primary key field named `hotel_id` of `HotelDetails`. I used `to_field` attribute for this, but it seems I am going wrong some where. It shows me error like

> **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BMH-1'**.

when I try to add the `hotel_id` 'BMH-1' in `RoomPriceDetails`. 'BMH-1'is a hotel id in `HotelDetails`. If I am wrong what is the best way to make my foreign key to point to my `hotel_id` field in `HotelDetails` to accept those values.

My models:

```
class RoomPriceDetails(models.Model):
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(HotelDetails, to_field='hotel_id')
    price_per_day = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class HotelDetails(models.Model):
    hotel_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='hotel_id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner_email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner_contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

Comment: are you sure `'BMH-1'` is the `hotel_id` ? [Autofield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/fields/#autofield) is an integer field as far as the doc knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autofield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#autofield) can only hold an integer, by default Django sets auto field.

> An IntegerField that automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise.

What you would like is add [primary_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) to your CharField

> `Field.primary_key`
>   If True, this field is the primary key for the model.

In your example:

```
class HotelDetails(models.Model):
    hotel_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='hotel_id', max_length=10)
```

Having primary key not being integer can decrease your DB performance